# nginx: [emerg] unknown log format

Tags: nginx, logging

I am trying to exclude pingdom from appearing on my nginx access log however getting error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown log format "if=$excluded_ua" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:55
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

In the config I am adding:

```
http {
...

  map $http_user_agent $excluded_ua {
         pingdom  0;
         ~Preload 0;
         default 1;
     }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$excluded_ua;

...
}
```

After correcting for the error, I am still seeing the Pingdom entries in my access file.

```
94.247.174.83 - - [26/Oct/2017:22:02:56 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 14832 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to include a log_format. The default one is "combined". Can you try `access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$excluded_ua;`?

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log

Comment: actually this doesn't produce an error, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure `$excluded_ua` is being evaluated correctly? Maybe you can try matching on `~*pingdom  0;`; `~*` will do case insensitive matching.

You may be able to verify if it is `$excluded_ua` not being evaluated correctly by forcing `if=0` and checking if all logs are excluded in `access_log`.

Comment: ok I have figured this out now thanks for pointing out to correct direction